# Raised pad for ornamental feature

Tags: concrete

I need to make a raised pad on soil about 16" above ground level and about 14' by 3' wide for an ornamental feature going on top. I was first thinking about doing this by forming out the box shape and filling it solid with concrete but I quickly realised I'll struggle with the forming. Now I'm considering laying a block/brick perimeter first to act as a form. But I'm having trouble deciding from these options on how to make up the height in the center:

1. Fill the cavity with crushed rock and compact well. Then pour a concrete pad on top.
2. Fill the cavity full of concrete.

Costs for both aren't going to differ too much in my case so thats not a factor.

Which would you do?
Would filling it with concrete make it less likely to shift and crack over time?

Thanks.

Comment: flip a coin if you have to ... nobody can decide for you

Comment: Could you forget the concrete and get decorative concrete blocks to stack and a slab of granite on top or something like that?

Comment: @SteveWellens I don't think I can source slabs of granite very easily. Plus, one that big would likely need a crane to lift. I'm planning to stucco the whole thing to get a uniform finish. I just need it to be relatively heavy, non combustible and able to be anchored to. Why are you against the concrete?

Comment: @jsotola if you don't know just don't comment.

Comment: Any form for that will need to be solid and staked, into the ground or else the cement will push the form apart when pouring.

Comment: @jsotola's answer is the only correct one for "what would you do" since you're asking for an opinion. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that opinion based questions are off-topic since there is no possibility of there ever being a "correct" answer because everyone has a different opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If costs are similar (which is highly unusual) concrete **with reinforcing.** Reinforcing is a very small portion of the cost of concrete, normally. It makes a huge difference in the results, though.

For your block wall to be a suitable concrete form, it should probably have a steel reinforced bond-beam, or at bare minimum ladder reinforcing steel placed in the joints. If frost is a factor in your area, the footing for that wall needs to start below frost level.

Large blocks of unreinforced concrete can crack badly, especially if subject to frost movement.

Depending what's available in your area, one option may be to use "engineered fill" or "foamcrete" to fill the bulk of the space with a relatively low cost, low strength material, and then top with a slab of normal concrete.

Comment: Thanks. It's a similar cost because I basically already have the materials for the concrete on hand. About the engineered fill option, is there much downside to it? It seems like a much easier option.